# Magento 2 Products not showing in categories and search (visible in backend)

Tags: search, category-products, magento2.3.0

Got an issue with displaying the products in **frontend** although they all can be seen in **backend**. Products also can't be searched but can be accessed via url e.g. `example.com/catalog/product/view/id/111769` so the product page works.

Things I've done so far:

- Cleared Cached
- Re-indexed everything
- Remove/Re-added products to the same category
- Removed/Reimported the products
- Made sure the products are enabled
- Made sure the items are in stock
- Made sure the inventory qty is more than 0
- Made sure the product visibility is set to "Catalog, Search"
- Made sure the products are assigned to website
- Disabled all custom modules
- Changed the custom theme to luma
- Upgraded Magento to 2.3.1
- Looked through magento, apache, mysql logs

Do you have an idea what the problem could be or what else could I try?

---

### Update 15.05:

Figured out that records in `catalog_product_index_eav` are not being generated and when I add the product record there manually it shows up in frontend.

Does someone has any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: i know you have checked he stock status but have you set the inventory qty to more than 0

Comment: yeah, checked that too, I'll add it to the list, thanks

Comment: is your instance in production or development? if production please switch so gives out errors.

Comment: it's in developer mode

Comment: Have you checked the category permissions that come as part of the Magento2 B2B module?

Comment: I haven't, where can I find those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the search index tables and there's an easy solution:
`Magento admin -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`
 - in **Search Engine** select, choose **Mysql** option and save
 - refresh cache
 - reindex, products should be there

Thanks to everyone who tried to help :)